# Feasability of using OpenCV with Python over a GPU on Windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, opencv

I have to read images coming from a camera, add some shapes with OpenCV and return the image to a webpage with Flask. This application is running in Windows 10. The detailed steps are:

- Reading the images from a camera is done. I have a Python wrapper for the C++ library which seems to work well.
- Adding shapes with OpenCV is done. I use the OpenCV wrapper for Python.
- Returning the image with Flask is the problem. For that, I need to convert the image from raw to JPG or PNG format with `cv2.imencode` (the OpenCV Python wrapper). Nevertheless, this slows down the frame rate of the video to be shown on the website.

I've seen at some places, that OpenCV can be used to perform some operations over the GPU (Nvidia GeForce RTX). I've tried with `cv2.UMat` just before calling `cv2.imencode` but there is no difference.

And here is my question:

- should I try with more Python wrappers (as described [here](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-3-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/))?
- should I start learning C++? Will I need to migrate all the existing application from Python to C++ or just a wrapper? Can this be done in a few lines?

Comment: Did you compile your code with optimizations enabled? If not, do that now.

Comment: The OpenCV library? Because all my code is in Python (at the moment).

Comment: I meant to say All of it.

Comment: I'm new on Windows (20 years of experience on Linux, but nothing on Windows). I've just installed the required dependencies/libraries with the Windows Installer, and the python application doesn't need any compilation. How do I enable the optimizations? It's for the GPU optimization or for the machine optimization?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally compiled [OpenCV-python](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) with the GPU flags, with the needed CUDA flags. It took me weeks to install all the needed dependencies (image libraries, video libraries, Fortran, LINPAK, BLAS...).

The result is that the call to `cv2.imencode` is way faster and I can see the GPU consumption increased in the resources manager of Windows.

Comment: How did you encode the gpuMat with opencv? Can you provide an example code? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I didn't use Umat at the end, compiling opencv with the adecuate flags was enough to use the GPU for the method imencode

Comment: When I try to encode the image using cv2.cuda_GpuMat I get an error saying: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'.