# GPU accelerated PNG encoding in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, png, gpgpu

PNG encoding in OpenCV on CPU is much slower than real time frame rate, e.g. 5Mp image `im` takes over 200ms on a modern PC with these settings:

```
cv2.imwrite("f.png", im, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_RLE])
```

Is there a GPU accelerated version, which can encode 5Mp images at 10fps or better with similar compression ratio as above?

---

Not being able to find GPU accelerated solution, I took advantage of my 6-core CPU. It provides stable 28fps, which is the maximum I can get from my AVT camera. Here is the code snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
def writePNG(path, image):
  cv2.imwrite(path, image, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_STRATEGY_RLE])


def frame_handler(cam, frame):
  global iFrame

  cam.queue_frame(frame)
  Process(target=writePNG, args=(f'{videoPath}/frame{iFrame}.png', frame.as_opencv_image(),)).start()
  iFrame += 1
```

Comment: if there is a hardware accelerated version then maybe more likely for imencode than for imwrite. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942454/feasability-of-using-opencv-with-python-over-a-gpu-on-windows

Comment: you could also try webp format with lossless 100 quality instead of png, but I dont know whether it is faster or not.

Comment: sorry, that was wrong. For webp, values > 100 mean lossless. So at least 101

Comment: @Micka That Q/A seems rather sketchy, just some anecdote from OP, no code, no real measurements shown. Raises more questions than it answers. Digging through the code, I can't see how `imdecode` could dispatch to GPU, AFAICT it just uses libpng and in recent versions libspng (which might be a little faster, but doesn't use GPU either). There's no sign of anything else PNG related in either main or contrib repos. I'd be happy to be proven wrong tho :)

Comment: I'd be kinda surprised tho, as I can't find much even outside OpenCV, other than some research papers. I can't even find any GPU-based Zlib-compatible library. There's some deflate implementation in nvcomp (which is now proprietary), but that say's it's deflate-like, not sure what to make of it. A parallelized CPU implementation would be more likely (there is pigz after all), and I can see few prototypes of parallel PNG (one written in Rust looks fairly sensible). Maybe that could be used via ctypes or some ffi, unless someone already wrote (or wants to write) a Python wrapper.

Comment: I guess by far the easiest approach, assuming OP has some cores spare, would be to just run the `imwrite` in a threadpool. Based on OP's numbers, 3 or 4 threads would be enough.

Comment: @DanMašek I used multiprocessing to max out available cores. I don't thing multithreading would work due to GIL and this being a CPU bound task (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: IIRC OpenCV releases the GIL for anything non-trivial, so threads work quite well with that. GIL is usually problem if bulk of the work is done by the interpreter. I have at least one answer here that shows that in practice, let me see if I can f ind it.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244613/3962537 -- there's a lot of Numpy and OpenCV doing the heavy lifting, and you can see that it scales rather nicely even with just threads.